# How to use Elasticsearch standard analyser without lower case

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, analyzer, standardanalyzer

Im trying to create an analyser in elasticsearch using the pre-sets of "standard" analyser but with one change - no lower casing of words.

Ive tried chaining the whitespace and standard analyser like so:

```
PUT /standard_uppercase
{
"settings": {
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "rebuilt_standard": {
      "tokenizer": "standard",
      "filter": [
        "standard",
        "whitespace"       
      ]
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

But this does not give the required results. Is there a way to overwrite only the lowercase part of an analyser but retail all the existing features of the standard analyser?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html#_definition)

> **Definition**
>
> The standard analyzer consists of:
>
> Tokenizer
>
> ```
>     Standard Tokenizer
> ```
>
> Token Filters
>
> ```
>     Standard Token Filter
>     Lower Case Token Filter
>     Stop Token Filter (disabled by default)
> ```

So, you could achieve your purposes in that way:

```
PUT /standard_uppercase
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "rebuilt_standard": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "standard"   
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```